# Scrolling a RecyclerView inside another RecyclerView automatically not working correctly

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

So am having this recyclerview which will contain holders of multiple types one of which could be a scrollable horizontal list of edge to edge images, that are being scrolled automatically and have a current item indicator. so for this i used a viewholder which will itself contain another recyclerview and a dots indicator( which itself is another recycler view, so basically recyclerview = a list of vh , where one of the vh =  2 horizontal recyclerview).

```
title
[A,B,C,D...]
[+ ---]

title
[A,B,C,D...]
[+ --]

title
[A,B,C,D...]
[+ --]

title
[A,B,C,D...]
[+ --]
```

My innermost recylerview of horizontal images is created something like this:

```kotlin
class ImageAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageVH>() {
    var imageResList = mutableListOf<Int>()
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) = ImageVH(parent, viewType)
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ImageVH, pos: Int)
    = holder.bindData(imageResList[pos % imageResList.size])
    override fun getItemCount() = Int.MAX_VALUE
}

class ImageVH(v: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v) {
    constructor(parent: ViewGroup, viewtype: Int) : this(
        LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_image, parent, false)
    )

    fun bindData(imageRes: Int) {
        Glide.with(itemView.context).load("").error(imageRes).into(itemView.ivImage)
    }
}
```

it is basically fooling the adapter to think as if i have a million images but will actually have just a few images. this creates an impression of circular scroll.

Next i will need something to change the dots indicator  of the second recyclerview. for this  i went into the parent of this recyclerview and attached an onScrollListener . The onScrollListener gives me 2 function: onScrolled and onScrollStateChanged.

- with `onScrolled` , i determine when to change the next dots recyclerview's state  to show the new dot. i do this via linear layout manager. when it gives  `findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition` as positive number .
- with `onScrollStateChanged()`, i run a kind of recursion, where whenever i get the state as SCROLL_STATE_IDLE, I post a handler to scroll the recyclerview to next item after 2 seconds. after 2 seconds, it will automatically smooth scroll and again fire the same event, causing the handler to fire the same action again.

so the code looks something like this:

```kotlin
data class Rails(val title: String, val images: MutableList<Int>,val autoscroll:Boolean =false)

class RailsAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<RailVH>() {
    var railsList = mutableListOf<Rails>()
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) = RailVH(parent, viewType)
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RailVH, pos: Int) = holder.bindData(railsList[pos])
    override fun getItemCount() = railsList.size
}

class RailVH(v: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v) {
    constructor(parent: ViewGroup, viewtype: Int) : this(
        LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_rails, parent, false)
    )

    private  var autoscrollImages = false
    fun bindData(rails: Rails) {
        autoscrollImages = rails.autoscroll

        with(itemView) {
            tvTitle?.text = rails.title

            rvImagers?.apply {
                adapter = ImageAdapter().also {
                    it.imageResList = rails.images
                    it.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
                PagerSnapHelper().attachToRecyclerView(this)
                isNestedScrollingEnabled = false
                onFlingListener = null

                addOnScrollListener(onScrollListener)
            }
        }

        if(autoscrollImages){
            bannerChangerHandler.postDelayed(bannerChangerRunnable,bannerChangerDelayMilllis)

        }
    }

    private val onScrollListener = object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
            //super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
            val bannerLLManager = itemView.rvImagers?.layoutManager as? LinearLayoutManager
            bannerLLManager?.let { linearLayoutManager ->
                val bannerCurrentPos = linearLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()
                if (bannerCurrentPos >= 0) {
                    val rvDotsDataListSize = 5
                    val positionInRange = bannerCurrentPos % rvDotsDataListSize
                    Toast.makeText(
                        itemView.context,
                        "highlight dot #$positionInRange",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }
            }
        }
        override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
            //super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState)

            when (newState) {
                RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE -> {
                    if(autoscrollImages){
                        Log.e(">>a>>", "RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE!")
                        bannerChangerHandler.postDelayed(bannerChangerRunnable, bannerChangerDelayMilllis
                        )
                    }

                }
                RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING -> {
                    Log.e(">>a>>", "RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING!")
                    bannerChangerHandler.removeCallbacks(bannerChangerRunnable)
                }
                else -> {
                }
            }


        }
    }

    private val bannerChangerHandler: Handler = Handler()

    private val bannerChangerRunnable = Runnable {
        itemView.rvImagers?.apply {
            val bannerManager = layoutManager as? LinearLayoutManager
            bannerManager?.let {
                val bannerCurrentPos = it.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()
                smoothScrollToPosition(bannerCurrentPos + 1)
            }
        }
    }

    private var bannerChangerDelayMilllis = 2000L

}
```

for brevity, assume whenever the toast is occuring, its going to scroll the 2nd dots indicator recyclerview .

This all seems to work in principle, but after sometimes the handler seems to fire twice or thrice , causing bad ux. sometimes it even goes berserks and  stops showing any logs or anything and just makes the rails run infinetely very fast, like handler firing an autoscroll runner every millisecond.

- [handlers firing 2-3 times](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10R9QPowL0ERJSWdsx5d2HCn55ATwJiqp/view?usp=sharing)

So any help with this? i am assuming something is wrong at the implementation level, like firing handler events could be handled better?

**Update:**
thanks to @ADM , I got this working. I tweaked it as per my requirements, and had to forgo of circular scroll support in the reverse direction, but the given solution was enough to answer my query. thanks!

Comment: You are posting same `Runnable` i.e `bannerChangerRunnable` again and again this can cause trouble because `bindViewHolder` can get call multiple times in that time period in normal scenario and also you are using and Delayed handler that's why too.

The Solution for this is Since Each Inner `RecyclerView` holding a seperate instance of `ImageAdapter` you should move handler implementation to `ImageAdapter`. You  can pass in a lambda to call inside `run` .

Comment: @ADM but what use is handler being passed to `ImageAdapter` ?  Currently, its `MainActivity<--RailsRecycler(+RailsAdapter)<--ImageRecycler(+ImageAdapter)` the railsAdpater will create a view for ImageRecycler and that view will have the power to change image recyler's position . how can this power be shifted to internal image recycler? can you please post an answer with some more explanation as i can't seem to imagine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Handler` is not an issue here its the `Runnable`. you are using and posting same `Runnable` each time thats why its getting piled up . You can not remove the previous call because you do not have a `Tag` or token to this delayed call . take a look at some of `Handler's` method like `sendMessageDelayed` these might help .

After giving it some thought i think you can move the Auto scroll part to `SnapHelper`. Not a full prove solution but i think it will work. You might have to put few checks in  `SnapHelper` . Give it a try and let me know . i haven't tested it.

```
class AutoPagedSnapHelper(private var autoScrollInterval: Long) : PagerSnapHelper() {
private var recyclerView: RecyclerView? = null
private var currentPage = 0
private var isHold = false

private val autoScrollRunnable = Runnable {
    recyclerView?.let {
        if (recyclerView?.scrollState != RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING && !isHold) {
            if (it.adapter != null) {
                val lastPageIndex = (recyclerView?.adapter!!.itemCount - 1)
                var nextIndex: Int
                nextIndex = currentPage + 1
                if (currentPage == lastPageIndex) {
                    nextIndex = 0
                }
                it.post {
                    val linearSmoothScroller = object : LinearSmoothScroller(recyclerView?.context) {
                        override fun calculateSpeedPerPixel(displayMetrics: DisplayMetrics): Float {
                            return MILLISECONDS_PER_INCH / displayMetrics.densityDpi
                        }
                    }
                    linearSmoothScroller.targetPosition = nextIndex
                    (recyclerView?.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager).startSmoothScroll(linearSmoothScroller)
                }
            }
        } else {
            postNextPage()
        }
    }
}

override fun attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView: RecyclerView?) {
    super.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView)
    if (this.recyclerView === recyclerView) {
        return
    }
    if (autoScrollInterval != 0L) {
        this.recyclerView = recyclerView
        this.recyclerView?.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState)
                if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE || newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING) {
                    val itemPosition = (recyclerView.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager).findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()
                    if (itemPosition != -1) {
                        currentPage = itemPosition
                        postNextPage()
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        postNextPage()
        recyclerView?.addOnItemTouchListener(object : RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
            override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(rv: RecyclerView, event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
                when (event.action) {
                    MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                        isHold = true
                    }
                    MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL, MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP -> {
                        isHold = false
                    }
                }
                return false
            }

            override fun onTouchEvent(rv: RecyclerView, event: MotionEvent) {}
            override fun onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(disallowIntercept: Boolean) {}
        })
    }
}

fun postNextPage() {
    recyclerView?.handler?.removeCallbacks(autoScrollRunnable)
    recyclerView?.postDelayed(autoScrollRunnable, autoScrollInterval)
}
companion object {
    private const val MILLISECONDS_PER_INCH = 75f //default is 25f (bigger = slower)
}
}
```

This should take care of auto change page. You do not have to use `scrollListener` in `Adapter`. Give it a try.

Comment: hi this didn't worked. i [tweaked it a little](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Vsbgj4PCQ5/)  as per my requirement, but it doesn't start neither manually nor automaticallly. the snap helper is working fine tho.  i am calling this via the following lines `val middleOfInfinity = Int.MAX_VALUE / 2 + (Int.MAX_VALUE % itemList.size) ; autoScrollPageSnapper=AutoScrollPageSnapper(bannerChangerDelayMilllis) ; autoScrollPageSnapper?.attachToRecyclerView(this) ; autoScrollPageSnapper?.forceStart(middleOfInfinity)`

Comment: I am guessing the view's internal handler is null. also regarding your previous comment on VH, anytime we run a handler.post with a runnable, its going to call bindviewholder, even if vh is no longer visible?  so i guess using a post will be always wrong in this scenario? any other time based class/function that i could use?

Comment: also, you did meant removing my on scroll listener right, or would i still need that? i mean , the old logic was a kind of recursion but in this way i don't see any recursion going on.

Comment: hey, i just went back to my original implementation and changed the runnable  definition to a function, i.e i changed  `private val bannerChangerRunnable = Runnable {...` to  `private fun bannerChangerRunnable() = Runnable {...`  . i think this will be creating a new instance of runnable every time we call it . i am currently not seeing the running rails bug,will test some more . but do you think this will fix it?

Comment: hey @ADM ,thanks a TON! for this approach.  i have almost got it working, it just seems to show the running rails bug  one time before auto correcting itself, just when the data is reloaded in the adapter. so do you know what could be a possible bug here? the logs show -ve dx value if you override  onScrolled too

Comment: and am guessing you are not doing much different, just ensuring that runnables and all our complex logic gets attached to recycler only once by relying on a system provided utility and view's post{}, right?

Comment: also, that onhold check was very neat, thanks!just one more thing, i need to be able to stopthe auto scroll when user is dragging the view on its own and only start if its idle. so for that i wrote my code in SCROLL_STATE_IDLE and not SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGABLE. so will that be too much different?

Comment: I think i already covered this in my code in the answer .

Comment: yeah i removed everything from the rails adapter and currently using this code

Comment: hey ADM , this is working perfectly, thanks a ton!!! i found the issue. actually my adapter was using Int.MAX to return list of items, and when i manually did linearLayoutManager.smoothScrollTo(Int.MAX /2), it would show the natural scrolling animation . removing that line made my recycler as inifinitely scrollable in 1 direction, but its now working. so can you help me with that? https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/vSFz9wT6qr/

Comment: also i am trying to add a global boolean support which will allow to autoscroll if enabled and gets disabled when user drags. currently i can't seem to get it working when kept as true, maybe i didn't understood your code completely. so any help there? (Same file, sorry for being too much dependent)

Comment: i saw a "move to chat popup" , but i can't see it now. any idea how we can do that?

Comment: I think i created a room, not sure how to move my chat over there . please join https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229650/q-66508479